# unable to display Wingdings font on my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: fonts, locale, unicode

I have installed Wingdings font but this is how its displayed.
I somewhere read that Wingding fonts are added to Unicode version 7.0.0 on July 16 2014. So I download the Unicode v7, a vivid package and have installed but still not effect.
I have also set my locale to en_IN.UTF-8

can someone please help me out here ? I am curious as to know how this stuff works

[image: ubuntu font viewer]

Comment: Isn't it rather a font issue? Which font are you using?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson like I wrote in question: Wingding fonts

Comment: Sorry about that stupid question. ;) See my answer below.

Comment: Unicode does not define *fonts* at all. Unicode 7 added some *characters* corresponding to some symbols that have long been available in Wingdings fonts but had not previously been coded as characters. So what do you mean by “Wingding fonts are not displayed”? The display of the added characters depends on fonts installed in your system and on the software used to display characters.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do have, same as you little boxes in place where symbols or letters should be,, when viewing with font viewer (ver: 3.8.0 on my xubuntu): here

[image: pic1]

but I tried to give a fontmatrix a try and voila, it shows all chars from Wingdings,,

[image: pic2]

So, I would say that it is only issue in programs that we use to view some fonts... I tried also to install fontforge, and it offers the same types but with powerfull editing functionality.. if you'll need. Free, and one of a kind program!

hth, k

Comment: you answer is helpful. but when I am importing that font using css to display in html. its not working. while on inspecting the browser does not shows any error. I am using `.ttf` format to import

Comment: I guess you are using @font-face right? did you generated font on your own or maybe via online service,, like www.fontsquirrel.com ?

Comment: one think to have in mind,, that is if I'm right Micro$oft font without webembade-ing rights.. see first if you can do this,, legally...? I would also suggest to use some other iconic fonts that are specially designed to be used on css, like font-awesome or fontastic.me etc..

Comment: yes I am uisng downloaded ttf font. do you mean that font cannot be used in CSS ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is commercial font, and if you bought it legally than it's ok to use it, for sure if license has 'webfont' support in it, like here, take a look: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ascender/wingdings/licensing.html

Comment: i google that font name and found it downloadable on some website. how could I know that its paid font ?

Comment: I can see that font in WPS office and fontforge. so finally we conclude that this font cannot be used with CSS ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the [unicode-data](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unicode-data) package that matters, and it looks like Ubuntu 14.04 has version 6.3. Utopic and Vivid have version 7.0, so you may want to try to install the Utopic or Vivid version of unicode-data. Haven't tested, though.

*Edit:*

Have you tried the package *fonts-opensymbol*?

```
$ dpkg -p fonts-opensymbol
Package: fonts-opensymbol
Priority: optional
Section: fonts
Installed-Size: 367
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: libreoffice (1:4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1)
Version: 2:102.6+LibO4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1
Replaces: ttf-opensymbol
Provides: ttf-opensymbol
Recommends: fontconfig
Size: 110464
Description: OpenSymbol TrueType font
 This package contains the OpenSymbol TrueType font included in
 LibreOffice. This font contains symbols (like fonts as Wingdings(tm)),
 bullets (needed for bullets in LibreOffice) and non-latin character
Homepage: http://www.libreoffice.org
Original-Maintainer: Debian LibreOffice Maintainers <debian-openoffice@lists.debian.org>
```

Comment: I installed unicode-data 7.0.2 but still wingdings font are not displayed

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: Just edited my answer.

Comment: I have newer version than that of yours

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: I meant: Have you tried to use OpenSymbol as font instead of wingdings?

Comment: in font viewer I can see OpenSymbol they dont appear as boxes but they dont have alphabets they look like some kind of symbols. but wingdings are still boxes. on the other hand in libre writer, i wrote something in english and formated it n OpenSymbol they all turned in to boxes and when formatted with wingdings the appear as some kind of symbols. this is crazy

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: I see. It was a thought, and I'm not an expert on the topic. Sorry.